Using multi-licensed code as a library in my proprietary software
I want to use the dual-licensed git-filter-repo as a library in my proprietary and commercial application, by this I mean:

I want to sell the application as a binary, executable or package but not disclose its source code.
I want to make money from this application.
I want to provide warranty and support for this application on various support plans that the users opt-in to.

git-filter-repo is dual licensed as such:

Main license file stating that most of the files under the repo are provided under the MIT Licence. I am interested in the git-filter-repo file, which I think is provided under the MIT License.
The MIT License file.
The GPL License file.

The project is still in planning phase hence I am experimenting before actual implementation and I do not want to break any license compliances.
There are two main ways in which I plan to use the git-filter-repo software:

Call as a subprocess from my application:
subprocess.run(['git-filter-repo', *args], check=True)


As a library:
import git_filter_repo as gfr



I need clarification on:

Do I need to open source my application if I used any of the above mentioned usages, i.e. subprocess or library?
If I am required to open souce my project then which license should I use so that it allows me and only me to sell my application as commercial and proprietary so that I can earn from it?
Can I still keep my source closed if there is some other way to use git-filter-repo apart from the subprocess or library call?
Can I obtain patent on my application design and/or code if I used git-filter-repo internally as mentioned above?

I have already been through:

Using an MIT licensed library in my project.
This question only talks about MIT License and not dual-license and I am not able to understand whether I need to open-source/link the source-code of git-filter-repo alongwith my code's documentation or user manual.

Is it legal to use GPL code in a proprietary, closed-source program by putting it in a separate, standalone program?.
2.a) Do I need to open-source my own application if I used the git-filter-repo as a library or a python import?
2.b) What are my obligations?

How to manage multi-licensed components in a project.
As git-filter-repo is dual-licensed, according to the answer to the question above, can I assume the MIT-license since it looks more permissive towards closed-source proprietary commercial software than GPL?


Any help is appreciated.

These are all great questions for your lawyer.

For clarification question 2, it depends on the license. If the code is coming from GPL or similar copyleft licenses, you can't change the license to do what you want. For your linked questions, the answer for #2 seems quite clear. As @bdb484 suggested, talk to your lawyer.

FYI, posting on multiple stackexchange sites is discouraged. Please either delete this post or the one at https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/15281/using-multi-licensed-code-as-a-library-in-my-proprietary-software.

For patent issue see here: https://google.github.io/opencasebook/patents/#mit-license  But really obtaining a patent means $$$ and patent lawyer, so you can probably leave it up to the lawyer.

@doneal24 this one is under a close vote for being a request for personal legal advice.
